# How to use EOBI simple binary encoding

Tags: binary-data

I am trying to use the [sbeTool](http://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding/wiki/Sbe-Tool-Guide) with the  [Eurex codecs](https://www.eurexchange.com/resource/blob/1896966/0bd1f5de377da4c0145c17262239ccf1/data/T7_EOBI_XML_Representation_v.8.1.0.zip):

```
JAVA -Dsbe.target.namespace=eobiV81 -classpath  "../sbe-tool-1.7.0.jar;../agrona-0.9.6.jar" uk.co.real_logic.sbe.SbeTool eobi81.xml
```

This eobi.xml file looks slightly different from the sample provided and the tool execution fails  (it succeeds on the the car.xml example file):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at uk.co.real_logic.sbe.xml.XmlSchemaParser.getAttributeValue(XmlSchemaParser.java:221)
        at uk.co.real_logic.sbe.xml.MessageSchema.<init>(MessageSchema.java:47)
        at uk.co.real_logic.sbe.xml.XmlSchemaParser.parse(XmlSchemaParser.java:105)
        at uk.co.real_logic.sbe.SbeTool.parseSchema(SbeTool.java:274)
        at uk.co.real_logic.sbe.SbeTool.main(SbeTool.java:199)
```

Can anyone help me find a way to get the xml compiling? I believe maybe the eobi.xsd file should be useful, but not sure how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eurex EOBI is not compliant with the SBE 1.0 standard. You can see this if schema validation is turned on for the SBE Tool. To parse Eurex messages you will need a different codec.